# Where to find pdb/symbol files for older operating systems (like Windows 2000)

Tags: windows, windbg

IT WAS NOT POSSIBLE TO OBTAIN THE SYMBOLS THROUGH THE MICROSOFT SYMBOLS SERVER as it is not possible to obtain them on the symbols server..

log windbg :

```
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to Windows 2000 2195 x86 compatible target at (Wed Jan  4 17:40:45.498 2023 (UTC - 2:00)), ptr64 FALSE
Kernel Debugger connection established.
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntoskrnl.exe - 
Windows 2000 Kernel Version 2195 UP Free x86 compatible
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0x80400000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x8046ccf0
System Uptime: not available
Fips device driver loaded successfully
Fips driver locked into memory
Fips driver unlocked from memory
```

I want to debug Windows.

Comment: Maybe the old SDK CD-ROMs from that era?

Comment: I am unsure if your question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/windows-2000-rtm-symbols) *might* have what you need.

Comment: To clarify, the 2000 SDKs and DDKs might still be in the MSDN / visual studio archives along with the old OS ISOs.

Comment: I think 2000 maybe used .dbg files and not .pdb (not that it matters).

Comment: last time i heard they were all still available to msdn subscribers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols for XP and later used to be available on the symbol server a couple of years ago but I think maybe Microsoft deleted them. There was a thread somewhere on [OSR](https://community.osr.com/categories/windbg) where a Microsoft developer claimed XP SP3 should still be available but I can't find it at the moment.

If you look at [Windows symbol packages for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols) Microsoft says

> We no longer publish the offline symbol packages for Windows.

This leaves you with Archive.org.

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110226001750/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx) leads to [http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/packages/Windows2000/RTM/Windows_2000_RTM_Symbols.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20200416133730/http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/packages/Windows2000/RTM/Windows_2000_RTM_Symbols.exe) but that refused to work for me.

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20040612110050/http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx) has more but you will have to view the source of the download page and pick out each URL by hand. Some of these work, some do not.

The symbols also seem to have been uploaded by others on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/windows-2000-rtm-symbols).

The final option would be to try to find the older SDK and/or DDK ISOs, you can probably find some symbols there.